# swift 3 array of structs -> cast to NSObject -> cast back => crash

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, nsobject, anyobject

The following code crashes on Swift 3, can anyone please explain why?

```
struct S {
    let a:Int
}

let t = [S(a: 8)]
let u:AnyObject = t as NSObject
let v:[S] = u as! [S]
```

Is that because in Swift 3 array of structs is NSObject (it's not in Swift 2) and it somehow can't be converted to NSArray well? And why is it NSObject?..

Comment: Does `let u:AnyObject = t as NSObject` even compile for you...? Arrays in swift are value types and does naturally not derive from the concrete class type `NSObject`. In Swift 2 implicit bridging between Swift native types and Obj-C types could allow for slightly confusing conversions, but implicit bridging facilities has been removed in Swift 3.

Comment: This is weird, since `let v = u as? [S]` works.

Comment: @dfri - yes, it compiles, may be it's a bug in Swift 3..

Comment: @silyevsk Ok, I've only tested for Swift 3 at the IBM sandbox (where it does not work).

Comment: @JAL - indeed, and then the optional can be unwrapped, so you solved the issue for me :)

Comment: Added an answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use a conditional binding with an optional downcast:

```
if let v = u as? [S] { /* */ }
```

Not sure why forced downcast wouldn't work though.  Might be something funky going on with `NSObject`.